# Resize/Scale multiple bitmaps(duplicate 1 bitmat over and over)

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I am trying to make a frame arround an uploaded picture by repeating 1 image over and over again. The user will have to enter the real dimentions of the picture and the image will be scaled acordingly so that the frame will look as big as it should. The problem is that when I get a bigger pickture and I scale the images something goes wrong and there is some smearing in the movie clip. When I move it to X:0 and Y:0 all is well. When I move it to the center of the screen the smearing is there.
Here's the code I use:

```
    public class frame_part extends MovieClip {

    public function frame_part(duplicationBitmap_org:Bitmap, neede_pcs_num_height:Number, order:String, rotation_num:int) {
        super();
        for(var i:int = 0; i < neede_pcs_num_height; i++) {
            var pc3:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var duplicationBitmap_org1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(uplicationBitmap_org.bitmapData);
            pc3.addChild(duplicationBitmap_org1);
            switch(order) {
                case("X"):
                    pc3.x = i * pc3.height;
                    break;
                case("Y"):
                    pc3.y = i * pc3.width;
                    break;
            }
            pc3.rotation = rotation_num;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a picture of what happens. [link text][1]

[1]: http://share1t.com/avaxsz See the left side. It is ok until a certain way and than it smears :(. Can anyone please help?

P.S. After the creation of this it is scaled with scaleX and scaleY accordingly.

Comment: If it helps the picture that I use and duplicate like 200-300 times is 400x500 px.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try flooring or rounding the x and y? like:

```
pc3.x = Math.floor(pc3.x);
pc3.y = Math.floor(pc3.y);
```

alternatively use:

```
pc3.x |= 0;
```

Which removes everything after the dot.

Comment: My guess is that it has nothing to do with the coordinates. If it was so it would be on the whole thing. In a previous version I was able to fix it with expanding the width and height of the frame but now it doesn't work.

Comment: Well I am not completely sure what you mean by smearing (maybe some screen?) but can't it be that it's just because of scaling? You know, scaling down will usually have some smoothing applied to look at least half decent.

Comment: I had the soothing but I removed it whyle I was testing some stuff. I tried with it again later on but it didn't help. And if it was the smoothing than the problem should be with the whole side of the frame not just 1/2 or 1/3 of it... It displays ok some percent of the frame and than the other part is somehow off.

Comment: Hmm, no idea. Maybe try something like: `pc3.y = i*pc3.width-1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found the problem. When I repeat the picture 100 times it make a frame wayyyy too big to handle. It is something like 50 000 x 40 000 px :). And somewhere there something goes wrong. The problem I fixed by useing 2 picktures. 1 big and 1 small. When I need a big frame I use the small pickture and repeat it 100 times :). When I need a small frame I use the big one and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a ton of elements/bitmaps to wrap around as a frame you should instead create a transparent bitmap/bitmapdata and clone/stamp the design into that and place it on top of the image that you want to frame. By keeping the frame design as one flat bitmap you will save a ton of memory overhead and make flash quicker and more responsive.